# Running python script on android studio using Chaquopy can't open Camera

Tags: java, python, android, android-camera, chaquopy

My python script uses camera to detect fingers and runs successfully on PyCharm but when trying to run it on android studio using chaquopy it gives error camera is not defined. 
I am new with chaquopy and cant find similar problems with other people or similar answers.

Java Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends PythonConsoleActivity {

    @Override protected Class<? extends Task> getTaskClass() {
        return Task.class;
    }


    public static class Task extends PythonConsoleActivity.Task {
        public Task(Application app) {
            super(app);
        }

        @Override public void run() {
            py.getModule("enders_keyboard_vision").callAttr("test");

        }
    }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import math
import enders_keyboard
"""import enders_keyboard_output"""

bg = None

def test():
    print("Yarraaabb")

def run_avg(image, aWeight):
    global bg
    if bg is None:
        bg = image.copy().astype("float")
        return
    cv.accumulateWeighted(image, bg, aWeight)

def segment(image, threshold = 10):
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

    global bg
    diff = cv.absdiff(bg.astype("uint8"), image)
    thresholded = cv.threshold(diff, threshold, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    cv.GaussianBlur(thresholded, (11, 11), 0)
    thresholded = cv.dilate(thresholded, kernel, 10)
    thresh = cv.threshold(thresholded, 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh = cv.erode(thresh, kernel, 20)
    conts,hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if len(conts) == 0:
        return
    else:
        segmented = max(conts, key=cv.contourArea)
        return (thresh, segmented)

def rough_hull(hull_ids, cont, max_dist):
    if len(hull_ids) > 0 and len(cont) > 0:
        res = []
        current_pos = cont[hull_ids[0]][0][0]
        points = []
        for point in hull_ids:
            dist = np.linalg.norm(cont[point][0][0] - current_pos)

            if dist > max_dist:
                res.append(point)
                current_pos = cont[point][0][0]
        return res
    else:
        return []


def get_mouse_pos(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(x, y)

def vector_proj(v1, v2):
    return np.multiply((np.dot(v1, v2) / np.dot(v1, v1)), v1)

def simulate_key(key):
    """enders_keyboard_output.type_key(key)"""
    print("ESHTAA")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aWeight = 0.5

    key_dict = {
        0 : "a",
        1 : "b",
        2 : "c",
        3 : "d",
        4 : "e",
        5 : "f",
        6 : "g",
        7 : "h",
        8 : "i",
        9 : "j",
        10 : "k",
        11 : "l",
        12 : "m",
        13 : "n",
        14 : "o",
        15 : "p",
        16 : "q",
        17 : "r",
        18 : "s",
        19 : "t",
        20 : "u",
        21 : "v",
        22 : "w",
        23 : "x",
        24 : "y",
        25 : "z"
    }

    camera = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    time.sleep(1)
    top, right, bottom, left = 10, 350, 350, 750
    num_fingers = 0
    num_frames = 0

    start_points = [
        (385, 235), #thumb
        (425, 125), #index
        (500, 105), #middle
        (560, 130), #ring
        (615, 210) #pinky
    ]

    start_center = (0, 0)

    current_points = start_points.copy()

    act = False
    last_found = [True, True, True, True, True]

    while(True):
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 700)
        frame = cv.flip(frame, 1)

        (height, width) = frame.shape[:2]

        roi = frame[top:bottom, right:left]

        gray = cv.cvtColor(roi, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

        inner = [False, False, False, False, False]
        outer = [False, False, False, False, False]

        if num_frames < 10:
            run_avg(gray, aWeight)
            cv.circle(frame, (int(height / 2), int(width / 2)), 30, (0, 0, 255))
        else:
            cv.imshow("background", bg/255)
            hand = segment(gray)

            if hand is not None:
                (thresholded, segmented) = hand
                #if cv.countNonZero(thresholded) > ((top - bottom) * (left - right) * 0.95):
                #    time.sleep(0.5)
                #    bg = None
                #    num_frames = 0

                #cv.drawContours(frame, [segmented + (right, top)], -1, (0, 0, 255))
                convex_hull = cv.convexHull(segmented + (right, top), returnPoints = False)
                hull = rough_hull(convex_hull, segmented, 40)

                #remove bottom two points
                #del hull[hull[0][:, :, 1].argmin()[0]]
                #del hull[hull[0][:, :, 1].argmin()[1]]

                if len(segmented) > 0:
                    hull_sorted = sorted(hull, key = lambda a : segmented[a[0]][0][1])
                    hull_sorted = hull_sorted[:min(len(hull_sorted), 5)]

                activated = []
                if act is False:
                    for point in range(5):
                        activated.append(False)
                        for pt in hull_sorted:
                            if math.hypot(start_points[point][0] - segmented[pt][0][0][0] - right, start_points[point][1] - segmented[pt][0][0][1]) < 25:
                                activated[point] = True
                        cv.circle(frame, (start_points[point][0], start_points[point][1]), 30, (255, 0, 0), thickness = -1 if activated[point] else 1)

                    num_fingers = 0

                    for active in activated:
                        if active is True:
                            num_fingers += 1
                    if num_fingers >= 5:
                        print("act")
                        act = True
                        m = cv.moments(segmented)
                        start_center = (int(m["m10"] / m["m00"]) + right, int(m["m01"] / m["m00"]) + top)
                else:
                    m = cv.moments(segmented)
                    current_center = (int(m["m10"] / m["m00"]) + right, int(m["m01"] / m["m00"]) + top)
                    center_diff = np.subtract(current_center, start_center)
                    for point in range(len(start_points)):
                        start_points[point] = np.add(start_points[point], center_diff)
                        start_center = current_center

                    thumb_inner = False
                    thumb_outer = False
                    found = [False, False, False, False, False]
                    for point in range(5):
                        vect = [start_points[point][0] - current_center[0], start_points[point][1] - current_center[1]]
                        mag = math.sqrt(vect[0]**2 + vect[1]**2)
                        inner[point] = False
                        outer[point] = False
                        for pt in hull_sorted:
                            if math.hypot(current_points[point][0] - segmented[pt][0][0][0] - right, current_points[point][1] - segmented[pt][0][0][1]) < 20 and math.hypot(start_points[point][0] - segmented[pt][0][0][0] - right, start_points[point][1] - segmented[pt][0][0][1]) < 40:
                                current_points[point] = (segmented[pt][0][0][0] + right, segmented[pt][0][0][1])
                                diff = np.subtract((current_points[point][0], current_points[point][1]), start_points[point])
                                adjusted_pt = np.add(start_points[point], vector_proj(vect, diff))
                                cv.circle(frame, (int(adjusted_pt[0]), int(adjusted_pt[1])), 30, (255, 0, 0), thickness = -1)
                                found[point] = True
                        if (not found[point]) and found[point] is not last_found[point]:
                            d = math.hypot(current_points[point][0] - current_center[0], current_points[point][1] - current_center[1])
                            current_points[point] = start_points[point]
                            if d < mag:
                                inner[point] = True
                                outer[point] = False
                            else:
                                inner[point] = False
                                outer[point] = True
                            cv.circle(frame, (current_points[point][0], current_points[point][1]), 25, (255, 0, 255))
                        last_found[point] = found[point]
                        cv.circle(frame, (start_points[point][0], start_points[point][1]), 30, (0, 255, 0), thickness = 1)
                        cv.line(frame, (start_points[point][0], start_points[point][1]), (int(start_points[point][0] + vect[0] * 15 / mag), int(start_points[point][1] + vect[1] * 15 / mag)), (0, 255, 0), thickness = 1)
                    cv.circle(frame, current_center, 25, (0, 0, 255))
                    thumb_dist = math.hypot(current_points[0][0] - current_center[0], current_points[0][1] - current_center[1])
                    thumb_vect = [start_points[0][0] - start_center[0], start_points[0][1] - start_center[1]]
                    thumb_mag = math.sqrt(vect[0]**2 + vect[1]**2)
                    if thumb_dist - thumb_mag < -15:
                        thumb_inner = True
                        thumb_outer = False
                    elif thumb_dist - thumb_mag > 15:
                        thumb_outer = True
                        thumb_inner = False

                    for finger in range(len(inner)):
                        if inner[finger] is True:
                            simulate_key(key_dict[(8 if thumb_inner else (16 if thumb_outer else 0)) + finger * 2])
                        elif outer[finger] is True:
                            simulate_key(key_dict[(8 if thumb_inner else (16 if thumb_outer else 0)) + finger * 2 + 1])


                #cv.drawContours(frame, [cv.convexHull(segmented + (right, top), segmented, 5)], -1, (0, 0, 255))
                cv.imshow("Thresholded", thresholded)

        cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        num_frames += 1

        cv.setMouseCallback("Video Feed", get_mouse_pos)
        cv.imshow("Video Feed", frame)

        keypress = cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF

        if keypress == ord("q"):
            break
        if keypress == ord("r"):
            num_frames = 0
            start_points = [
                (385, 235), #thumb
                (425, 125), #index
                (500, 105), #middle
                (560, 130), #ring
                (615, 210) #pinky
            ]
            act = False
            bg = None
            time.sleep(0.1)
        if keypress == ord("s"):
                    enders_keyboard.search(num_fingers)

camera.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error :

com.chaquo.python.PyException: NameError: name 'camera' is not defined
    at .enders_keyboard_vision.(enders_keyboard_vision.py:262)
    at .importlib._bootstrap._call_with_frames_removed(:219)
    at .importlib._bootstrap_external.exec_module(:783)
    at .importlib._bootstrap._load_unlocked(:671)
    at .importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(:975)
    at .importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(:991)
    at .importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(:1014)
    at .importlib.import_module(**init**.py:127)
    at .chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_Python_getModule(chaquopy_java.pyx:153)
    at com.chaquo.python.Python.getModule(Native Method)
    at com.chaquo.python.console.MainActivity$Task.run(MainActivity.java:21)
    at com.chaquo.python.utils.ConsoleActivity$Task$1.run(ConsoleActivity.java:359)

Answer (score 1):

Your module is not being loaded as `__main__`, so that entire block of code will not be run. Instead of putting it in a `__main__` block, put it in a function and call it using `callAttr`.

Separately, the Chaquopy build of OpenCV doesn't currently support accessing the camera directly. The easiest workaround is to capture the image using Java, save it to a temporary file, and load that file in Python.

Comment: I know the part considering the main, I am just testing a small method called " test ", regarding the camera part, Can you tell me more details about capturing the image using Java and saving it to a temporary file and then loading it into Python ?

Comment: I can open camera using java on android studio, But how can I use it in python code instead of the used one in python ??

Comment: The `camera` variable is assigned in the `__main__` block, but then it's accessed further down at the module top level. So that's why `getModule` is failing, and it won't even get as far as calling `test`.

Comment: I'm sure you can find examples of how to save a camera image to a file in Java. Then you can pass the filename to Python using `callAttr`, and load it with OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Go and add explicit permission to use camera in your android project config.
All external resources (camera, mic, internet request, gps request) accessed via chaqoupy channel need explicit permission, otherwise it'll return not defined / not found errors.